# CoreData NSPredicate attribute name

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I've started programming an iPhone app using CoreData and trying to make my codebase as maintainable as possible. Therefore I would like to avoid hard-coded strings such as:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", aName];
```

Instead I would like to be able to write something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", Person.name, aName];
```

That way I would get the compiler to check whether `name` is a property of the entity `Person` and avoid spelling mistakes.

With this code though I'm getting the following error at compile time:
Property `name` not found on object of type `Person`

`Person` being of type `NSManagedObject` and automatically generated by Xcode from my `MyApp.xcdatamodeld`.

`name` is a simple string attribute of the entity `Person`

I've googled up and SOed up quite a lot already for an answer to this specific issue. I've also tried using `property_getName` and `NSPropertyDescription` with not luck so far.

Thanks in advance for you help,

Joss.

Comment: It does not work that way, you would still have to supply `@"name"` to the `@K` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do use Mogenerator, per Kendall's excellent suggestion, in the auto-generated classes you will get three `struct`s declared in the header - `EntityNameAttributes`, `EntityNameRelationships`, and `EntityNameFetchedProperties`. So for instance, if your entity is named `Person`, and had an attribute `name`, you could get access to the key using `PersonAttributes.name`. This would allow you to avoid having hard-coded key names in your application code.

Comment: I did not know that was included in the default templates.  Thats the way to go for sure then.  Great answer!  Joss, you should accept this answer (click on the checkmark outline to the left and it will mark it as accepted).

Comment: @CarlVeazey: Wonderful answer! Exactly what I was looking for. That was my very first question on SO, real happy!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `Person.name` does not exist because "name" is a property of a person instance, not a class level property.

I'm not sure there's a really clear path from a compiler-checked method name to a string.  You can always use lower level methods to access method signatures from a class and get strings from them, but the starting point for those is an un-checked string (either C or ObjC).

In general use of predicates will give you errors if you get the name wrong, so any testing that uses a predicate will verify you got the method name correct.

You should be using Mogenerator to generate data objects for use with your model.  In that case you could look into changing the templates to add a method called something like "stringForMethodNamed*Name*" and include that as one of the parameters in the formatted predicate.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer Kendall! I've just heard about Mogenerator today ;-). I guess it's time I look into it then. I wish I could vote up your answer. I'm a noob on SO though and don't have enough reputation.

Comment: No worries, if you accept an answer you will gain some reputation.